# not work round Float for swift 4

Tags: swift, rounding, swift4

```
let value:Float = 5.678434
let roundedValue = round(value * 100) / 100
```

roundedValue   Float   5.6784339

how to get 5.67  or 5.68?

Comment: The result can be different from 5.68 due to the limited precision of binary floating point numbers (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), but is should be close to 5.68 and not 5.6784339. Are you sure that you print the correct variable?

Comment: I am getting 5.68 here too, do not know if you are checking it correctly. Also, maybe check with `roundf` instead of `round`.

Comment: If you want properly rounded to nth decimal position, you should use [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal), instead of `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Float {
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Float {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Float(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}

let floatNumber:Float = 3.67565676

print(floatNumber.rounded(toPlaces: 2))
```

> //prints 3.68

Comment: This is what OP already does, only written as an extension method. Your answer does not explain the problem, or how your code solves it.

Comment: the question was pretty clear “how to get 5.67 or 5.68?”